# What does "it" refer to?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood

At the pre climax scene of [Once Upon a Time in Hollywood (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_in_Hollywood), before 
being attacked by a group of hippies, Rick spoke to his dog Brandy:

> Rick: Hey. I am doing the best I can under the circumstances. Now, I
>   do not want to get into **it** tonight.

What does "it" refer to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an english language understanding problem.

Rick in this case does not want to get into a discussion/argument about the thing he’s doing the best he can under the circumstances.

I haven’t seen the film and don’t know the context of this scene. But it seems Rick is stressed out and doesn’t want to talk/fight about whatever it is.

Comment: To be more specific; earlier in the movie there’s a scene where he’s feeding the dog and arguing with the dog because the dog is whining while he’s preparing the dinner.

Answer (score -1):

'I do not want to get into it tonight'

This is reference to a cliched protest users of LSD and similar hallucinogens (including Cannabis) often make with regards to any unnecessary stress or activities they are expected to perform under the influence - "Hey. I am doing the best I can under the circumstances". Those circumstances being of course Cliff's drug impairment.

This notion is along similar lines of 'you are blowing my high' or that attendance to such issues could precipitate a 'bad trip' or some similar psychedelic crises, reinforcing how wasted Cliff is following his evening walk with his special cigarette.

Comment: Despite desperately trying not to refute or dv the first answer, the user stated themselves that they had not seen the film and in the case of this line by Cliff context is EVERYTHING and speaks more to this characters motivations than general observations about the use of English. Just because I know more about illicit drug use than would be considered polite or healthy does not make me wrong.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it could also be because your answer is one long sentence. Perhaps you could break it up a bit?

Comment: Will give it a whirl Longshanks - believe me - one only has to take a look at my post history to see I am the first to admit when I feel I have provided a bad answer and I have a genuine belief this is not one of those occasions...